# Post Multipart/form-data content type and send file to a website

Tags: excel, vba, api

I would like to send request with "POST" method to a website using Excel VBA.

There are few parameter in json format I need to set to post: action=gettoken, id=123, code=456,token = 123abc,doc=something.docx

It is Multipart/form-data content type for Content Type.

I tried the following code but it returns error

```
Sub POST_multipart_form_data()
    
    Dim oFields As Object
    Dim sBoundary, boundary As String
    Dim sPayLoad As String
    Dim sName As Variant
    Dim filePath, filePaths As String
    Dim token As String
    Dim fileContent As String
    Dim fileName As String
    
    
    
    filePath = "//C:/"
    fileName = "something.docx"
    filePaths = filePath & fileName
    Open filePaths For Input As #1
    fileContent = input$(LOF(1), #1)
    Close #1
    Debug.Print "fileContent" & fileContent
    
    token = "123abc"
    Set oFields = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With oFields
        .Add "action", "gettoken"
        .Add "id", "123"
        .Add "code", "456"
        .Add "accesstoken", token
        .Add "doc", fileName


    End With
    boundary = CreateBoundary
    sBoundary = String(6, "-") & boundary
    sPayLoad = ""
    For Each sName In oFields
        sPayLoad = sPayLoad & "--" & sBoundary & vbCrLf
        sPayLoad = sPayLoad & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""" & sName & """" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        sPayLoad = sPayLoad & oFields(sName) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    Next
    sPayLoad = sPayLoad & "--" & sBoundary & vbCrLf
    sPayLoad = sPayLoad & "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    sPayLoad = sPayLoad & fileContent & vbCrLf
    sPayLoad = sPayLoad & "--" & sBoundary & "--"
    
    Dim fileS
    Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    ado.Type = 1 'binary
    ado.Open
    ado.LoadFromFile filePath & fileName
    ado.Position = 0
    fileS = ado.Read
    ado.Close

    ado.Open
    ado.Position = 0
    ado.Type = 1 ' binary
    ado.Write ToBytes(sPayLoad)
    ado.Write fileS
    ado.Write ToBytes(vbCrLf & "--" & boundary & "--")
    ado.Position = 0
    'ado.savetofile "c:\tmp\debug.bin", 2 ' overwrite


    'Debug.Print ado
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "https://api/example", False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & sBoundary
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Length", LenB(sPayLoad)
        .send sPayLoad
        Debug.Print .responseText ' Erreur de login : Verifier vos identifiants !
    End With
    
End Sub

Function CreateBoundary() As String
    Dim chars As String
    chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    Randomize
    Dim boundary As String
    boundary = ""
    For i = 1 To 32
        boundary = boundary & Mid(chars, Int(Rnd() * Len(chars) + 1), 1)
    Next i
    CreateBoundary = boundary

End Function

Function ToBytes(str As String) As Variant

    Dim ado As Object
    Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    ado.Open
    ado.Type = 2 ' text
    ado.Charset = "_autodetect"
    ado.WriteText str
    ado.Position = 0
    ado.Type = 1
    ToBytes = ado.Read
    ado.Close

End Function
```

Error msg:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: `filePath = "//C:/"` Is this on Windows or a Mac ?

Comment: Seems like it's telling you POST is not accepted by that endpoint.

Comment: @CDP1802 Hi, this is on Windows

Comment: @TimWilliams, Hi, yes, may I ask if this is because the code is not correct?

Comment: Do you have a link to the api documentation ? What api method are you trying to invoke ?

Comment: There's no way for us to know without any knowledge of the actual endpoint you're trying to use.